# What do operator methods do? (poll, invoke, execute, draw & modal)

Tags: python, operator

I've seen the functions called poll and invoke used in scripts. I'm curious what these are for and when they are called.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

For a comprehensive description of operators and their use see:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html

For a quick run-down

- `poll`, checked before running the operator, which will *never* run when poll fails, used to check if an operator can run, menu items will be greyed out and if key bindings should be ignored.
- `invoke`, Think of this as "run by a person". Called by default when accessed from a key binding and menu, this takes the current context - mouse location, used for interactive operations such as dragging & drawing. *****
- `execute` This runs the operator, assuming values are set by the caller *(else use defaults)*, this is used for undo/redo, and executing operators from Python.
- `draw` called to draw options, typically in the tool-bar. Without this, options will draw in the order they are defined. This gives you control over the layout.
- `modal` this is used for operators which continuously run, eg: fly mode, knife tool, circle select are all examples of modal operators. Modal operators can handle events which would normally access other operators, they keep running until they return `FINISHED`.
- `cancel` - called when Blender cancels a `modal` operator, not used often. Internal cleanup can be done here if needed.

***** - note, button layouts may set the context of operators to invoke or execute. See: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.operator_context

Comment: I've never been quite sure of this, is `invoke` called after you make changes in the redo panel? It seems from the description like it shouldn't be, but I can't find anything for certain.

Comment: how do you ignore the poll function when calling the operator from a handler in python?  I always get nonetype object has no attirbute type (because that's what my poll is asking for).  I can check if it's non, but I just wondered if there's a way to bypass it completely?  EXEC_DEFAULT doesn't work.