# How to delete a material from a duplicated object? Sanity Check

Tags: python, materials, add-on

I must be misunderstanding something. I really need a sanity check.

I'm trying to duplicate the active object, then delete all the material slots from it without affecting the original.

==== EDIT======
Thanks for the answers, it looks like I only have this problem when the code is part of an operator:

```
def invoke(self, context, event) :
    def deleteMatsFromDuplicate():

        scene = context.scene

        # Duplicate the model
        obj = context.active_object
        obj.select = False
        obj_copy = obj.copy()
        obj_copy.location += Vector((1, 1, 1))
        mesh_copy = obj.data.copy()
        obj_copy.data = mesh_copy
        scene.objects.link(obj_copy)
        scene.objects.active = obj_copy
        obj_copy.select = True
        obj_copy.name = "copy"

        #loop thru and remove all
        for ms in obj_copy.material_slots:
            bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()
    # end deleteMatsFromDuplicate

    deleteMatsFromDuplicate()

    return {"FINISHED"}
#end invoke
```

Comment: Any Help would be appreciated!

Comment: This code worked for me (Blender 2.77a) after I added `import bpy` to the start.

Comment: Is the script you've posted part of an operator? If you just run these lines from a text editor, this should work, but from within an operator there is a potential catch to it. In case it is an operator, please post the rest of the code too if possible.

Comment: Test code using simple operator template, http://www.pasteall.org/71940/python are you invoking the operator or calling form script, in which case you need to `bpy.ops.some_op('INVOKE_DEFAULT')` See http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19431/15543

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming by the behaviour of question code (pre edit) that the material_slot link is 'OBJECT' rather than 'DATA'.  Code below should work on either. Used `copy()` method of object and mesh to create a copy, added (1,1,1) to the location, linked to scene, made active, and removed all material slots.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

obj = context.active_object
obj.select = False
obj_copy = obj.copy()
obj_copy.location += Vector((1, 1, 1))
mesh_copy = obj.data.copy()
obj_copy.data = mesh_copy
scene.objects.link(obj_copy)
scene.objects.active = obj_copy
obj_copy.select = True
#loop thru and remove all
for ms in obj_copy.material_slots:
    bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()
```

Comment: Works great! Just out of interest: I ever thought when linking an object to the scene like `link(obj_copy)` we need to update the scene via `scene.update()`. Do you know why this is not relevant here?

Comment: @poor My guess is `scene.objects.link(o)` may force a scene update, as does `scene.frame_set(f)` would have to look at code to be certain.

Comment: It works like a charm :) Except, if I put the code in 'invoke' or 'execute' then I get the same problem I had before. Why is that?