# how to set a delay in blender execution

Tags: python

Scripting in Blender, is it possible to insert an object, wait 1 second, and put a second object?
I used the time.sleep(1) (after that the first object has been imported into the scene) but it doesn't work because it put both the objects after 2 seconds. What's the problem??

```
import time
if x == 3:
    bpy.ops.wm.append(directory= ...., filename= .....)
    time.sleep(1)
elif x == 2:
    bpy.ops.wm.append(directory= ..., filename= .....)
```

Comment: It's probably actually doing what you want, but it won't update the UI until the script has finished executing. You want to use a [modal operator](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/75354/28015).

Comment: .. in particular a [Modal Timer Operator](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7885/how-to-run-a-python-script-at-regular-intervals/7887#7887)

Answer (score 2):

Probably bad idea, but might just work for simple fiddling:

```
import bpy
import functools

# Add 10 cubes in 10 seconds
def add_cubes(x = 0):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(x,x,0))
    x += 1
    if(x < 10): # Run add_cubes(x) after 1 second
        bpy.app.timers.register(functools.partial(add_cubes,x), first_interval=1) 

add_cubes()
```

https://docs.blender.org/api/latest/bpy.app.timers.html