# Default stringproperty arguements

Tags: properties

I have a class with a few StringProperties, 
I'm wondering if there's a way reset the StringProperties to defaults each time I call the class.
I tried adding defaults like this but if I call with 'YES' it remembers the 'YES' the next time I call it.

```
cutline = bpy.props.StringProperty(name='Cutline',default='NO')   
live = bpy.props.StringProperty(name='Live',default='NO')   
insetted = bpy.props.StringProperty(name='Insetted',default='NO')   
drawtype = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Draw Type",default='BOUNDS')
```

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/94079/15543)  Possibly duplicate question if you are using props in operator class.