# Execute function before draw menu

Tags: python, scripting

I am traying to make a popup menu that will add a modifier if the object has none and then draw the menu, or just draw it if the modifier is already on it.

But i am not sure how to go about it, the script i have is working, but it only adds the modifier after i close the panel. Tried creating another class just for the operation but didn't work also.

```
import bpy

class DC_MT_popup_star(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "popup.dc_star"
    bl_label = "Str Popup"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"

    def execute(self, context):
        pass

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager       
        return wm.invoke_popup(self, width=200)
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        split = layout.split()
        col = split.column()

        ob = context.object
        mm = ob.modifiers
        
        row.label(text="Bevel")
   
        if "Bevel" in ob.modifiers:           
            col.prop(mm["Bevel"], "width", text= "Offset")
            col.prop(mm["Bevel"], "segments", text= "Segments")
            col.prop(mm["Bevel"], "angle_limit", text= "Angle")
            col.prop(ob.data, "auto_smooth_angle", text="Smooth")
        
            col = split.column()
            col.prop(mm["Bevel"], "limit_method", text= "")
            col.prop(mm["Bevel"], "use_clamp_overlap", text= "Clip")
            col.prop(ob.data, "use_auto_smooth", text="Auto Smooth")
       
        else:
            mm.new(name="Bevel", type='BEVEL')
            mm["Bevel"].use_clamp_overlap = False
            
            return {'FINISHED'}

classes = (
    DC_MT_popup_star,
)
register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: You can either add an invoke method: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19431/31447 or add a second operator and call this one while execution, not sure what's better in your case. Notice your class name should be `DC_OT_po...` since class type is operator. Does that help?

Comment: @brockmann Does exactly what i wanted, thank you!, i thought invoke was just for ui stuff. But just so i know.. when you say that it can be done with a second operator, this new operator would still have to be reference on the invoke to be triggered first than the panel draw?

Comment: @brockmann Could you add a short answer? Or could we pass this off as a duplicate?

Comment: Only  draw properties in a draw method.  Re my previous comment with `mm` ... above would be something like  `bm = ob.modifiers.get("Bevel")` and to test if it does not exist `if bm is None:` and then add a new one `bm = ob.modifiers.new(...)`   then will be `layout.prop(bm, "width")`   This is known as  "by reference" (regardless of name) rather "by key" `ob.modifiers["key"]`.  Blender automatically appends numbers if two objects have same name, eg a second bevel modifier would be given the name "Bevel.001"  if "Bevel" is taken.  To be sure `[m for m in ob.modifiers if m.type == 'BEVEL']` is

Comment: a list of all bevel modifiers on the object.