# How do you know if a collection has been clicked on by the user using Python?

Tags: python, scripting, collections

How can I create a panel that allows me to add custom properties (`StringProperty`, `BoolProperty`, etc) for Collections? I want to show a GUI in the object properties when the user clicks a collection in the outliner. To create a panel you normally inherit from `bpy.types.Panel` and implement the `draw()`. The `poll()` function can be used to determine if the panel should be shown or not. The obvious approach is to use this feature. But how would this `poll()` look like? How do you know if a collection has been clicked by the user as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: selected collection in outliner]

When "my-collection" is clicked/selected I want to show a panel in the object properties. But how do I know  if a collection has been clicked?

**Update 1**

[image]

I'll try to clarify the issue a bit more. In the image above I've made the "Sub" collection active. When I print the name `C.collection.name` you see that it prints "Sub".  Now, let me make "Cube" active:

[image]

Now, when I print `C.collection.name` it prints "Sub" again; and although that's correct, that's not the info I'm trying to retrieve. I need to query some other context value which would give me the collection when "Sub" is active and "Cube" when the object is active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s easier than you might think: Either get the collection in context ([`C.collection`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html?highlight=collection#bpy.context.collection)) or the collection of the active *View Layer* ([`C.view_layer.active_layer_collection`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ViewLayer.html?highlight=active_layer_collection#bpy.types.ViewLayer.active_layer_collection)). Both attributes return a reference to the selected collection in the *Outliner* allowing to access the name of the collection by using its `name` attribute to compare against.

Adding the following poll method to your panel class will only return `True` in case the selected collection is called `MyCollection` and thus display the panel:

```
@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    return context.collection.name == "MyCollection"
```

[image]

Code based on `ui_panel_simple.py` template:

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.collection.name == "MyCollection"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(obj, "name")

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Further reading:

- [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui)
- [What do operator methods do? (poll, invoke, execute, draw & modal)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19416/what-do-operator-methods-do-poll-invoke-execute-draw-modal)

Comment: Thanks brockmann! There are  a couple of things that don't work with this approach. 1. I actually don't want to specifically check for "My Collection"; I want any collection to work; but I think you just added the check for `return context.collection.name == "MyCollection"` as an example. 2. The `active_layer_collection` also has a value when I select an object in in the collection itself. I want to know when the collection is selected/active in the outliner; like if it has the blue background (not sure how to describe this better). Then I can toggle a gui for the object or for the collection.

Comment: As mentioned, you can get the "selected/active/blue" collection using `C.collection`, it's a reference so you've got access to all properties of that collection. In case you want to display properties per collections or per object *in context*, you don't need any poll method, would basically always be true -> Just add a condition to your draw method whether an object or collection is selected or just for both, done. @roxlu Does that help?

Comment: Thanks @brockmann! I've tried to clarify the question a bit more, see **UPDATE 1** above. Maybe I need something like "outliner.active_node" (which I haven't found). And yes, what you suggest can work too but that's not exactly what I was trying to solve; but thanks for the suggestion; it might be the only thing that's currently possible.

Comment: So you'd like to get the active element in the *Outliner*? There is nothing like that... and honestly it doesn't matter in this case, you can have a panel for each element (object and collection) and can have one panel displaying the properties if one of them is active, even a sub-panel for the object in your main panel @roxlu

Comment: Ok thanks @brockmann if there is currently no way to get the active element in the Outliner then this is the best solution, thanks so much for your suggestions!