# Blender's Simple Operator Example not working

Tags: python, operator

I am just learning programming and am having difficulty running this example code from Blender's official python documentation on the quick start page: https://docs.blender.org/api/2.93/info_quickstart.html

It said to copy and paste what is show below, but the last sends an error message in the system console for the last line( the test call). If I comment it out, no error is sent, but no operator is shown in the 3D viewport's F3 search menu when I type in "simple".

This is the error message in the system console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\north\Downloads\scripting for artists.blend\Text", line 35, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 132, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.simple_operator.poll() failed, context is incorrect
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

I am using Blender version 2.93.0

Python:

```
import bpy


def main(context):
    for ob in context.scene.objects:
        print(ob)


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()
```

Comment: consider posting the error message.

Comment: Thanks. Just added the error message.

Comment: As the message suggests: your poll method failed, one object needs to be active in order to run the operator, related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19416/what-do-operator-methods-do-poll-invoke-execute-draw-modal If you want to run the operator without having one object *active*, just remove the poll method.

Comment: Thanks. I have now tried running the script with a selected object, but an operator still isn't showing up when I search simple in the F3 menu.

Comment: Can not confirm: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt4cT.png

Comment: I tried running in a new file and in this. The operator still isn't showing up. https://pasteboard.co/KeNOrAh.png. My mouse is in the 3D viewport when I search.

Comment: It does show up in the console when I look at the autofill options, but not in my 3D viewport search.

Comment: Try to enable *Developer Extras* (Edit > Preferences > Interface).

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much.