# How do you enable/disable operator buttons depending on enum list prop?

Tags: python

Hello I want my button to be disabled when a certain variable from a enum list property has been selected and enabled again when some other variable has been selected. How can I achieve this?

sample code:

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    scene = context.scene
    addonPrefs = scene.addon
    
    layout.prop(addonPrefs, "variables")
    layout.operator(addonExec.bl_idname, text="SAMPLE", icon="RENDER_RESULT") 

    #Results I want -> if addonPrefs.variables == "foo": disable operator button; else: enable operator button
```

Comment: i think you need to do that in the `poll` function https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19416/what-do-operator-methods-do-poll-invoke-execute-draw-modal

Comment: Do you wish to not display the button when it is disabled or do you wish to display it but show that it is disabled? In either case I would use an `if/then/else` with the test returning true if you want enabled.  Don't have an else clause if you want to not display.  Have an else clause that draws a label instead if you want to show disabled.  AFAICT [`UILayout.operator`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.operator) doesn't have a 'display disabled' option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do it like this:

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    scene = context.scene
    addonPrefs = scene.addon
    
    layout.prop(addonPrefs, "variables")

    op_row = layout.row()
    if addonPrefs.my_attr == "foo":
        op_row.enabled = False
    op_row.operator(addonExec.bl_idname, text="SAMPLE", icon="RENDER_RESULT")
```

You create a separate sub-layout and then set that layout's ["enabled"](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=layout#bpy.types.UILayout.enabled) attribute depending on the props condition.