# Camera won't be aligned to Current View with Python scripting

Tags: python, add-on, blender-internal-render-engine

This is the full code of a simple add-on. The first camera is aligned to view but when I add more than one camera, the rest won’t be aligned.

Is there a solution? I tried Temp_override but no luck.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Pro Camera",
    "blender": (3, 60, 0),
    "category": "3D View",
}

import bpy

class ProCameraPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Pro Camera"
    bl_idname = "PT_ProCameraPanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Tools'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        # Add a new camera
        layout.label(text="Add a new Camera")
        layout.operator("scene.assign_camera", text="Assign a Camera")

        layout.separator()

        # Select a camera lens
        layout.label(text="Select a camera Lens:")
        layout.prop(context.scene, "pro_camera_lens", text="Lens")

        # Add a horizontal line
        layout.separator()

        # Enable/Disable Depth of Field checkbox
        layout.prop(context.scene.camera.data.dof, "use_dof", text="Enable DOF")

        # Focus on Object field
        layout.prop_search(context.scene.camera.data.dof, "focus_object", context.scene, "objects", text="Focus on Object")


class OBJECT_OT_assign_camera(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "scene.assign_camera"
    bl_label = "Assign a Camera"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        # Add a new camera
        camera_data = bpy.data.cameras.new(name="Camera")
        if camera_data is None:
            return {"CANCELLED"}

        my_camera = bpy.data.objects.new("Camera", camera_data)

        if my_camera is None:
            return {"CANCELLED"}

        bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(my_camera)
        context.scene.camera = my_camera

        # Align the new camera to view
        bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view()

        return {"FINISHED"}

def update_camera_lens(self, context):
    selected_lens = context.scene.pro_camera_lens

    # Set the active camera's lens based on the selected option
    if context.scene.camera:
        if selected_lens == 'WIDE':
            context.scene.camera.data.lens = 24.0
        elif selected_lens == 'STANDARD':
            context.scene.camera.data.lens = 50.0
        elif selected_lens == 'PORTRAIT':
            context.scene.camera.data.lens = 80.0
        elif selected_lens == 'TELE':
            context.scene.camera.data.lens = 135.0
        elif selected_lens == 'SUPER_TELE':
            context.scene.camera.data.lens = 240.0

# Define the camera lens options
lens_options = [
    ('WIDE', 'Wide - 24mm', 'Wide angle lens - 24mm'),
    ('STANDARD', 'Standard - 50mm', 'Standard lens - 50mm'),
    ('PORTRAIT', 'Portrait - 80mm', 'Portrait lens - 80mm'),
    ('TELE', 'Tele - 135mm', 'Telephoto lens - 135mm'),
    ('SUPER_TELE', 'Super Tele - 240mm', 'Super Telephoto lens - 240mm'),

]

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ProCameraPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_assign_camera)
    bpy.types.Scene.pro_camera_lens = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        items=lens_options,
        name="Camera Lens",
        description="Select a camera lens",
        default='WIDE',
        update=update_camera_lens
    )

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ProCameraPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_assign_camera)
    del bpy.types.Scene.pro_camera_lens

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! Do you want to prevent the context error when in-camera? If so, I'd suggest to add a [poll() method to your operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/latest/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.poll) and return `context.space_data.region_3d.view_perspective != 'CAMERA'`. See: [What do operator methods do?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19431/3710) Does this help?